# facebook SBjsonparser leak

Tags: ios, facebook, json

So the best way to fill you in on what is happening is probably to show you this

http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v246/homojedi/Screenshot2012-07-24at135229.png

Strangely I have no hand in this as this is the facebook ios SDK doing calling all of this SBJson parser stuff as i had no clue of it's existence until i did a memory leak test due to my app telling me that it has had a memory warning lvl 1 or 2.

You may want some code as you may be as baffled while i reduced most the code to just this and it still seems to happen

```
-(void)OnLoad
{
_permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", @"publish_stream", nil] retain];

if( _facebook == nil )
{
    _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"359953307393080" andDelegate:self];
}

[self CheckForPreviousAccessToken];

if(_isConnected)
{
    [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
    [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=installed" andDelegate:self];
    [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];

}
}

- (BOOL) CheckForPreviousAccessToken
{
_isConnected = NO;

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if( [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"] )
{
    _facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    _facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];

    if(![_facebook isSessionValid])
    {
        [_facebook authorize:nil];
        _isConnected = NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        _isConnected = YES;
    }
}


return _isConnected;
}
```

Anyone have any idea as to what is causing these numerous leaks?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through magic and/or witchcraft this little issue has ceased to exist, and the strangest thing is i did not explicitly attempt to correct it...I was just doing some general leak patching and i must have been leaking something quite heavily as it now no longer turn up in leak instruments...My apologies i should have attempted to fix the leaks straight away rather then leave them in lieu of getting more features integrated.